# How to create a form in shape of rhomb?

Tags: c#

How to create a form in shape of rhomb?
I managed to create a shape in form of ellipse with the help of this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath myPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
            myPath.AddEllipse(45, 60, 200, 200);
            Region myRegion = new Region(myPath); 
            this.Region = myRegion;
        }
```

How can I do it but making rhomb?

Comment: What exact problem you have? You don't know how rhombus look like? OR how to draw it? Or how to change function?

Answer (score 2):

Use `myPath.AddLines` instead of the `myPath.AddEllipse`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        myPath.AddLines(new[]
            {
                new Point(0, Height / 2),
                new Point(Width / 2, 0),
                new Point(Width, Height / 2),
                new Point(Width / 2, Height)
            });
        Region = new Region(myPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is helpful you should mark this answer as accepted: [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Above answer by @Dmitry helped me a lot. However, it does not draw a complete rhombus, as claimed. The last segment is not drawn due to absent final point, which must coincide with the starting point. Line array should contain five points, not four.

I have made some corrections and come up with this function, which draws a rhombus withing a given rectangle:

```
private void DrawRhombus(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rectangle)
{
  using (GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath())
  {
    myPath.AddLines(new[]
    {  
      new Point(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y + (rectangle.Height / 2)),
      new Point(rectangle.X + (rectangle.Width / 2), rectangle.Y),
      new Point(rectangle.X + rectangle.Width, rectangle.Y + (rectangle.Height / 2)),
      new Point(rectangle.X + (rectangle.Width / 2), rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height),
      new Point(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y + (rectangle.Height / 2))
    });
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1))
      graphics.DrawPath(pen, myPath);
  }
}
```